# Receiving Windows Authentication prompt when Windows authetication is enabled on server

Tags: iis, internet-explorer-9

Here is what i have tried:

1. Configured Windows authentication on IIS 7.5.
2. Disabled anonymous authentictaion.
3. Made IE settings (adding to trusted sites,selecting use automatic authentictaion).
4. NTLM provider is used.
5. Turned server UAC to low.
6. Added sites to all zones and verified.

there is no issue with configuration as it works from client.
Now here is the issue:

Login to webpage works but if i close and reopen the  webpage i receive windows authentication dialog. These is just a random behavior and occurs every time i close and reopen IE.

This issue is observed only on windows 2008 Server R2. Accessing the server form client works fine and issue is not observed.

Application uses java.